RVIZ hangs on "Forcing OpenGL version 0."
I've installed ROS on my 2017 iMac Pro (Sonoma 14.5, Radeon Pro Vega 56 8 GB) using CONDA following the instructions in this video, How to install ROS on Mac.
However, when I try to run RViz as an initial test it hangs here:
Last login: Thu Jul  4 09:17:51 on ttys001
(base) kmu@Kevins-iMac-Pro ~ % conda activate ROS
(ROS) kmu@Kevins-iMac-Pro ~ % rviz
[ INFO] [1720103874.766136000]: rviz version 1.14.10
[ INFO] [1720103874.766171000]: compiled against Qt version 5.12.9
[ INFO] [1720103874.766178000]: compiled against OGRE version 1.10.12 (Xalafu)
[ INFO] [1720103874.774307000]: Forcing OpenGl version 0.

How do I install/link OpenGl to fix this?
